# Extend a Generic Type With Another Generic

Tags: swift, generics

Is it possible to extend a generic type with a where clause requirement containing another generic?

Basically something like this:

```swift
class WeakStore<Element: AnyObject> {
    weak var value: Element?

    init(_ value: Element) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

extension Dictionary where Value == WeakStore<Element> {
    public subscript(weak key: Key) -> Element? {
        get {
            self[key].value
        }

        set {
            if let exists = self[key] {
                exists.value = newValue
            } else {
                self[key] = WeakStore(newValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To clarify, this does not build and provides numerous errors. Additionally, while what prompts this specific question IS trying to get a weak dictionary working, please stay on topic about how to get a generic type extended with another generic (if even possible) as it is something that applies well beyond this specific use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it can be done quite this way. (I'm not actually certain why; it feels like it's just syntax and compiler features, but it's possible that there's something deeper I haven't discovered.)

I can, however, be done by adding a protocol:

```
public protocol WeakStoreType: AnyObject {
    associatedtype Element: AnyObject
    var value: Element? { get set }
    init(_ value: Element)
}

extension WeakStore: WeakStoreType {}
```

This just wraps `WeakStore` into a protocol, and then conforms WeakStore to that protocol, replacing a generic parameter with an associatedtype.

There are a few mistakes in your Dictionary extension, but they can be fixed as follows:

```
public extension Dictionary where Value: WeakStoreType {
    subscript(weak key: Key) -> Value.Element? {
        get {
            self[key]?.value
        }

        set {
            if let exists = self[key] {
                exists.value = newValue
            } else if let newValue = newValue {
                self[key] = Value(newValue)
            } else {
                self[key] = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll wait a couple days to mark as the answer to see if there's a better answer, but I would guess you're probably right that this would be the only way (right now at least) to do this. (as you said - seems like syntax and compiler features). Thanks for the dictionary fixes! I was mostly writing blind without syntax support in Xcode since it obviously didn't compile! :P